# Charging 3.2V 6000mAh LiFePO4 batteries (32700)

Tags: charge, lifepo4

I bought one 3.2 volt 6Ah LiFePO4 battery, which is called 32700:

[image]

For charging, I have a lot of li-ion TP4056 charging modules, but I have read that these batteries differ from lithium-ion batteries.

On google, I can't seem to find much information about the charger. Many online shop sell chargers for these batteries that are supposed to be in 4 groups (12.8 volts LiFePO4,) but I have only one battery, and I don't need several of them.

What's the best and cheapest way available in the market to charge these 32700 batteries for long-term usage?

Comment: [TP5000](https://www.ebay.com/itm/262610039940?hash=item3d24c73484:g:hnsAAOSwgmJXx5~j) does both Li-ion and LiFePO4.

Comment: Some Lithium charger, that you can set the output voltage or you change the sense feedback resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LiFe is different than LiPo or Li-Ion. Model aircraft chargers can charge single cells. They can also charge multiple cells of various chemistries. But they tend to cost more than your typical charger.

What are you using this for? Can you just get a battery holder and stick four of them in series and charge all four at once?

Comment: I'm using that battery to drive some lights after boosting the voltage. I can't stack 4 of them together because the cost will go up.

Comment: What I mean was a battery holder where you charge all four at once, and you take them out and use them one at a time.

Comment: No, I don't want to purchase 4 of them to charge all at once. Also, if I use one at a time, I have to make sure all batteries are discharged at the similar levels otherwise if I charge them for hours one battery with higher voltage can get damaged easily. So for me, it will be best bet if I can only use the one battery...

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options of charging LiFePo4 with Li-ion chargers if they support this:

- set cut-off voltage to 3.6V or 3.65V at max
- set stop-charge current at 200mAh; when the cell gets near 3.6V it will drain way less current, so that's a way of detecting it doesn't need to charge more

Both ways work fine, I've tested them with plenty of chargers not designed for LiFePo4.

Cheapest way with cheap Li-Ion charger: just monitor the charge and remove the battery at 3.6V if you can't automate anything.